# What is the difference between Serializable, and System.Serializable?

Tags: unity, serialization

What is the difference between `Serializable`, and `System.Serializable`?

I'm guessing `SerializeField` is only for attributes of a class. What is the difference between the above two, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, there is no difference - `System.Serializable` is just the fully qualified name of `Serializable`.

C# has this notions of *namespaces*; a namespace is a way to organize code (it's a "space for (type) names") - think of a namespace as of a box that contain stuff you might want to use. This helps organize things and avoid naming conflicts (if, say, two independently developed libraries use the same name for a class).

So, the Serializable attribute is declared/placed within the System namespace. When you say `System.Serializable`, you're just saying "get Serializable from System".

But if you have a `using System;` statement at the top, you can omit the namespace and just write `Serializable`; the compiler can then infer that it means `System.Serializable`, saving you a few keystrokes.